# *ngFor force prints in ascending order

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an object that I am trying to display in markup. But *ng keeps printing it in ascending order. Desired outcome is for elements to be printed in the order that they are. This is my stackblitz code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5nr2uk

Comment: the best way is to convert the object to an array, this way you will keep the desired order

Comment: @AlonYampolski Not true, converting the data is more work than using the provided pipe.

Comment: as per documentation, the '| keyvalue" transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.

Comment: @trichetriche don't forget that the order of the JSON properties might vary so that the initial assumption that they will keep their order is incorrect. This is why i suggested using an array (or a nested array) in the first place

Comment: @Alon if they vary, that's because the data has varied, which means the user/admin has control over the data and chose to edit it. They will keep their initial order, provided that "initial" means "unaltered data".

Comment: @trichetriche this is true as long as the list is hard-coded instead of being taken from some remote location

Comment: @AlonYampolski even when taken from some remote location, the order will be kept, as long as the data is unaltered ! (If the remote server changes the order, Angular can't do sh*t, but as long as Angular doesn't touch the data, the order will be kept as is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As per the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe), you can provide a custom compare function to the pipe.

Simply provide a function that returns zero everytime.

```js
customCompare(a, b) {
  return 0;
}
```

```html
*ngFor="let key2 of key.value | keyvalue:customCompare;"
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erwita?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: makes sense :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As the description in official API doc:

> The output array will be ordered by keys. By default the comparator
>   will be by Unicode point value.

This pipe also provides an optional function parameter to re-define sort order:

```
{{ input_expression | keyvalue [ : compareFn ] }}
(a: KeyValue, b: KeyValue) => number
```

More detail [here](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)